# trying to install and use rabbitmq server

Tags: rabbitmq

I installed by using 
`brew update` and `brew install rabbitmq`. 
Then tried to stop the server and start it again (I tried to install by downloding the source before).

`rabbitmqctl stop` but I get 
 `Stopping and halting node rabbit@localhost ...

```
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: [rabbit@localhost]

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- localhost: [{rabbit,61707},{rabbitmqctl33002,62384}]

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmqctl33002@Dev-MacBook-Air'
- home dir: /Users/ohad
- cookie hash: aeUlHJghkW6Yr7EMVbRJTg==`
```

which I reccon means there is no proccess, so I tried starting again:

```
rabbitmq-server
```

and I get

```
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "localhost"

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: [rabbit@localhost]

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- localhost: [{rabbit,61707},{rabbitmqprelaunch33047,62398}]

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmqprelaunch33047@Dev-MacBook-Air'
- home dir: /Users/ohad
- cookie hash: aeUlHJghkW6Yr7EMVbRJTg==
```

Comment: What's the output of `ps aux|grep rabbit` ?

Comment: 10x, completely missed that solution. still new to linux based os..

Comment: killed that process and restarted and it worked!